# javascript code prevents NaN but not allowing me to type decimals on keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-listener

```js
$('#cost').keyup(function(){

  // value is either the inputed numbers or 0 if none
  $(this).val(parseFloat($(this).val()) || 0);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='cost' />
```

I wanted to prevent NaN from happening so I have value default to 0 and it works fine.  However, when I input numbers, it will not allow me to add a decimal or move the cursor back for edit the input.  I'm sure this has something to do with the type of event listener, but I'm stumped and I've looked everywhere.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe check the value on `blur` instead of `keyup`?

Comment: General rules: don’t modify values on `keyup`; don’t throw out user input. In this case, it’s likely best to use an `<input type="number" />`.

Comment: You shouldn't be validating your input on the `keyup` event, but on `focuslost` or on the `submit` event.

Comment: Thank you to all of you that have provided input.  I've tried all of them and I think they are all great solutions.  However, I found that using BLUR instead of keyup as suggested by @uom-pgregorio  is the most suitable for my web application.  Again, thank you everyone!

Answer (score 2):

The `keypress()` event may make more sense in this context, because it's not triggered when moving the cursor.

Instead of setting the value, return `false` if the key isn't numeric or a decimal:

```js
$('#cost').keypress(function(e) {
  if(!/[0-9\.]/.test(e.key)) {  //allow only numbers and the decimal point
    return false;
  }
  
  if(/\./.test($(this).val()) && e.key==='.') { //prevent decimal from being entered twice
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='cost' />
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are updating the value of input field each time a key is pressed cursor is reset to last position. Following prevents update when value is not NaN. Hope it helps!

```js
$('#cost').keyup(function(){

  // value is either the inputed numbers or 0 if none
  let val = parseFloat($(this).val());
  if (isNaN(val)) {
      $(this).val(0);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='cost' />
```

Please note that input for `parseFloat` input like `0e1023` is valid and if input is starting with a valid number remaining part is ignored. For instance: `parseFloat('100asd')` would give `100`. You should follow Ryan's comment and use number type instead. You can check availability of number input [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-number)

Answer (score 0):

To allow only numbers I call from onKeyPress this function which I put in a helper class in my project:

```
function keyIsNumberOrEdition(key, floatsAllowed = false) {
    var res = (  (['Tab', 'Backspace', 'End', 'Home', 'ArrowLeft', 'ArrowUp', 'ArrowRight', 'ArrowDown', 'Delete'].indexOf(key) > -1) ||
        (Number.isInteger(Number(key)))  );
    return floatsAllowed ? res || (key == ',') : res;
}
```

The call:

```
element.onkeypress = function(e, true) {
     return keyIsNumberOrEdition(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery Plugin – Numeric from here](http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/numeric/)

```js
$("input#cost").numeric();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type='text' id='cost' />


<script >

/*
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2006-2014 Sam Collett (http://www.texotela.co.uk)
 * Dual licensed under the MIT (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php)
 * and GPL (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/gpl-license.php) licenses.
 *
 * Version 1.4.1
 * Demo: http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/numeric/
 *
 */
(function(factory){if(typeof define === 'function' && define.amd){define(['jquery'], factory);}else{factory(window.jQuery);}}(function($){$.fn.numeric=function(config,callback){if(typeof config==="boolean"){config={decimal:config,negative:true,decimalPlaces:-1}}config=config||{};if(typeof config.negative=="undefined"){config.negative=true}var decimal=config.decimal===false?"":config.decimal||".";var negative=config.negative===true?true:false;var decimalPlaces=typeof config.decimalPlaces=="undefined"?-1:config.decimalPlaces;callback=typeof callback=="function"?callback:function(){};return this.data("numeric.decimal",decimal).data("numeric.negative",negative).data("numeric.callback",callback).data("numeric.decimalPlaces",decimalPlaces).keypress($.fn.numeric.keypress).keyup($.fn.numeric.keyup).blur($.fn.numeric.blur)};$.fn.numeric.keypress=function(e){var decimal=$.data(this,"numeric.decimal");var negative=$.data(this,"numeric.negative");var decimalPlaces=$.data(this,"numeric.decimalPlaces");var key=e.charCode?e.charCode:e.keyCode?e.keyCode:0;if(key==13&&this.nodeName.toLowerCase()=="input"){return true}else if(key==13){return false}var allow=false;if(e.ctrlKey&&key==97||e.ctrlKey&&key==65){return true}if(e.ctrlKey&&key==120||e.ctrlKey&&key==88){return true}if(e.ctrlKey&&key==99||e.ctrlKey&&key==67){return true}if(e.ctrlKey&&key==122||e.ctrlKey&&key==90){return true}if(e.ctrlKey&&key==118||e.ctrlKey&&key==86||e.shiftKey&&key==45){return true}if(key<48||key>57){var value=$(this).val();if($.inArray("-",value.split(""))!==0&&negative&&key==45&&(value.length===0||parseInt($.fn.getSelectionStart(this),10)===0)){return true}if(decimal&&key==decimal.charCodeAt(0)&&$.inArray(decimal,value.split(""))!=-1){allow=false}if(key!=8&&key!=9&&key!=13&&key!=35&&key!=36&&key!=37&&key!=39&&key!=46){allow=false}else{if(typeof e.charCode!="undefined"){if(e.keyCode==e.which&&e.which!==0){allow=true;if(e.which==46){allow=false}}else if(e.keyCode!==0&&e.charCode===0&&e.which===0){allow=true}}}if(decimal&&key==decimal.charCodeAt(0)){if($.inArray(decimal,value.split(""))==-1){allow=true}else{allow=false}}}else{allow=true;if(decimal&&decimalPlaces>0){var dot=$.inArray(decimal,$(this).val().split(""));if(dot>=0&&$(this).val().length>dot+decimalPlaces){allow=false}}}return allow};$.fn.numeric.keyup=function(e){var val=$(this).val();if(val&&val.length>0){var carat=$.fn.getSelectionStart(this);var selectionEnd=$.fn.getSelectionEnd(this);var decimal=$.data(this,"numeric.decimal");var negative=$.data(this,"numeric.negative");var decimalPlaces=$.data(this,"numeric.decimalPlaces");if(decimal!==""&&decimal!==null){var dot=$.inArray(decimal,val.split(""));if(dot===0){this.value="0"+val;carat++;selectionEnd++}if(dot==1&&val.charAt(0)=="-"){this.value="-0"+val.substring(1);carat++;selectionEnd++}val=this.value}var validChars=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,"-",decimal];var length=val.length;for(var i=length-1;i>=0;i--){var ch=val.charAt(i);if(i!==0&&ch=="-"){val=val.substring(0,i)+val.substring(i+1)}else if(i===0&&!negative&&ch=="-"){val=val.substring(1)}var validChar=false;for(var j=0;j<validChars.length;j++){if(ch==validChars[j]){validChar=true;break}}if(!validChar||ch==" "){val=val.substring(0,i)+val.substring(i+1)}}var firstDecimal=$.inArray(decimal,val.split(""));if(firstDecimal>0){for(var k=length-1;k>firstDecimal;k--){var chch=val.charAt(k);if(chch==decimal){val=val.substring(0,k)+val.substring(k+1)}}}if(decimal&&decimalPlaces>0){var dot=$.inArray(decimal,val.split(""));if(dot>=0){val=val.substring(0,dot+decimalPlaces+1);selectionEnd=Math.min(val.length,selectionEnd)}}this.value=val;$.fn.setSelection(this,[carat,selectionEnd])}};$.fn.numeric.blur=function(){var decimal=$.data(this,"numeric.decimal");var callback=$.data(this,"numeric.callback");var negative=$.data(this,"numeric.negative");var val=this.value;if(val!==""){var re=new RegExp("^" + (negative?"-?":"") + "\\d+$|^" + (negative?"-?":"") + "\\d*" + decimal + "\\d+$");if(!re.exec(val)){callback.apply(this)}}};$.fn.removeNumeric=function(){return this.data("numeric.decimal",null).data("numeric.negative",null).data("numeric.callback",null).data("numeric.decimalPlaces",null).unbind("keypress",$.fn.numeric.keypress).unbind("keyup",$.fn.numeric.keyup).unbind("blur",$.fn.numeric.blur)};$.fn.getSelectionStart=function(o){if(o.type==="number"){return undefined}else if(o.createTextRange&&document.selection){var r=document.selection.createRange().duplicate();r.moveEnd("character",o.value.length);if(r.text=="")return o.value.length;return Math.max(0,o.value.lastIndexOf(r.text))}else{try{return o.selectionStart}catch(e){return 0}}};$.fn.getSelectionEnd=function(o){if(o.type==="number"){return undefined}else if(o.createTextRange&&document.selection){var r=document.selection.createRange().duplicate();r.moveStart("character",-o.value.length);return r.text.length}else return o.selectionEnd};$.fn.setSelection=function(o,p){if(typeof p=="number"){p=[p,p]}if(p&&p.constructor==Array&&p.length==2){if(o.type==="number"){o.focus()}else if(o.createTextRange){var r=o.createTextRange();r.collapse(true);r.moveStart("character",p[0]);r.moveEnd("character",p[1]-p[0]);r.select()}else{o.focus();try{if(o.setSelectionRange){o.setSelectionRange(p[0],p[1])}}catch(e){}}}}}));    </script>
```